# Procedures in Gnuplot

Tags: function, gnuplot, procedure

Is there a way to have procedures (or C-like functions) in Gnuplot? I need something really simple, just something like:

```
function func1()
{
 var1 = "string1";
 var2 = var1."string2";

 return var2;
}
```

to make my gnuplot scripts a little bit more compact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gnuplot supports (simple) functions with arguments:

```
func1(x)=x."string2"
```

More complicated "inline" functions can be created if you're using gnuplot 4.4:

```
func1(x)=(var1=x, var2=var1."string2", var1.var2)  #returns x.x."string2"
```

In this form, the last portion of the function is what is returned (`var1.var2`) and the statements are evaluated left to right.

If you want to have functions which accept no parameters, you can (often) use macros:

```
set macro
funcmacro='"string1"."string2"'
print @funcmacro
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I'm using gnuplot 4.4, I'll try both "inlining" and macros.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You can concatenate strings in gnuplot with something like

```
strcat(str1,str2) = sprintf("%s%s",str1,str2)
str3 = strcat("string1","string2"); print str3
```

The first line is the function definition, the second line is just an example of usage.  You can read more in the "User-defined variables and functions" section of the [gnuplot documentation](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.6/gnuplot.pdf) (it is under the "Expressions" section; you may have trouble searching for the string 'user-defined' in the pdf because of the 'fi' character generated by LaTeX).

Comment: I didn't think about `sprintf` for this purpose ... Interesting.  I think I would still prefer the operator verision: `strcat(s1,s2)=s1.s2`, but it doesn't really make much difference I don't think. +1 for pointing out that gnuplot has lots of C's functions already built in.

Comment: @andyras: I usually use the dot `.` to concatenate strings. My question was about if there were any way to create a procedure or a "non-math" function within a gnuplot script.

Comment: @mgilson: I also like the '.' operator, but I had forgotten about it myself!  Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider looking at the Pyxplot plotting package http://pyxplot.org.uk, which has very similar syntax to gnuplot (albeit cleaned up), but which also has a lot of the features of a scripting language. It has subroutines, which should do exactly what you're asking for.